Calculating weighted cosine similarity between vectors of words
I have two word lists, where each word is representative of each topic. A topic is created from a collection of documents (tweets in this case). Not all words would’ve appeared an equal number of times in the collection of documents, which is why it has an associated tf-idf weight (the number next to each  word).
topic1 = [('blue',.1), ('red',.05), ('sky',.01)]
topic2 = [('water',.5), ('fire',.1), ('earth',.02)]

I am trying to calculate the cosine similarity between the vectors, but also account for the tf-idf weighting of each word, where words with higher tf-idf weights will have more influence on cosine similarity.
Is there a commonly accepted way to account for individual weightings when doing vector similarity? How would I implement this?

Cosine similarity is not the best option because the data is not a vector.
Better options could be Kullback–Leibler divergence or Hellinger distance. Both algorithms quantify the similarity between two discrete probability distributions. In your case, that would be the similarity of the tf-idf scores for each collection of words. If you use Python, both algorithms are implemented in gensim.

Thanks for this answer! I realized I lost sight of my original question, though, and re-asked it here. If you're interested, I would love to know your thoughts. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/129284/calculating-topic-vector-similarity-based-on-document-frequency
