Calculating topic vector similarity based on document frequency
I am looking into ways to calculate the similarity of two topic vectors, where each dimension of a vector is a tuple made up a word describing the topic, along with the document frequency (tf-idf) of that word. I would like to account for the document frequency when measuring the similarity between topics, rather than just the number of matching words, and am looking for suggestions about how to do this.
As an example, given these 3 topics:
topic1 = [('blue',.8), ('red',.4), ('sky',.1), ('boy',.01)]
topic2 = [('water',.5), ('fire',.1), ('sky',.05), ('boy',.02)]
topic3 = [('blue',.7), ('fire',.1), ('earth',.02), ('screen',.1)]

For topic1, if I was just counting the number of matching words, I would say that topic2 is most similar, because 2 of the words match.
However, the two matching words, 'sky' and 'boy', have relatively low document frequency scores in topic2, .05 and .02, respectively. On the other hand, both topic1 and topic3 contain 'blue', and this word has a much higher document frequency in topic3, .7.
Given these two scenarios, how might I go about incorporating tf-idf scores into measuring similarity, going beyond just counting the number of matching terms? Could I add up the tf-idf of all matches? Would I take the average? Should I use a transformation such as the log of each score? Any suggestions would be appreciated.
